# One review per user in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I have product's review on product page now. But logged-in customer gives review more then once. I need only one review from one customer, not more than that.

Can you please suggest??

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to modify the review form as per the customer who is logged in. If they have already given review, then dont display. You can take help of this:

I looked into `Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\Collection` and found this method.

Here you can find this method :

```
/**
     * Add customer filter
     *
     * @param int|string $customerId
     * @return $this
     */
    public function addCustomerFilter($customerId)
    {
        $this->addFilter('customer', $this->getConnection()->quoteInto('detail.customer_id=?', $customerId), 'string');
        return $this;
    }
```

So in the above $customerId, pass the customer ID from the customer session array and just use an if loop for this.

Hope this helps.